# How to capture the terminal log of script to a file?

Tags: python, linux, stdout, stderr

I have a `python` script which runs succesfully from the Linux terminal. I am able to collect the terminal output to a file using a `shell script` when I run my `python` script.

Now I want to collect the terminal output from the `python script` itself. But unable to do so.

> I want to do this using `python` only not using any `shell` or `unix` scripting

I have done like below in my `python file`:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, f1, f2):
        self.f1, self.f2 = f1, f2
    def write(self, msg):
        self.f1.write(msg)
        self.f2.write(msg)

outfile = open('outfile', 'w')

sys.stdout = outfile
sys.stderr = Tee(sys.stderr, outfile)
```

This part of code in the `python file` prints both `stderr` and `stdout` to a outfile.

How can I capture the whole terminal output to a single file.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the whole terminal output"?
The code above does already write everything to `outfile`.
Although using `contextlib.redirect_(stdout|stderr)` would be easier.

Comment: @YSelf My code prints only `print` statements into the file, I want all the logging that shows up on the `terminal` to be included as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with the requirement of having `python` in your `PATH`, then I'd call another python process to run your main script.

In your top-level script, use the `subprocess.Popen` to start your desired script in a child process. Then use `subprocess.Popen.communicate()` to get the output streams from the process (and probably pass any command-line arguments into the process).

You might even be able to redirect all std* output to files just with Popen, but this really depends on your needs and whatnot. `communicate()` seems pretty useful for what you might want to do.

- [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)
- [subprocess.Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your code:        `os.system('pdv -t %s > 123.txt' % epoch_name)`
You could also look into this: [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)